# error message WeMos d1 mini: A fatal esptool.py error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header

Tags: arduino-esp8266

I've tried to connect my WeMos d1 mini with arduino and tried to upload my code to WeMos. However, there comes the error message: A fatal esptool.py error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header.

I have tried to change the upload speed, but to no avail.